# Attempting to Run Eigen Benchmark with OpenBLAS Backend

Tags: eigen, openblas

I'm trying to run Eigen's benchmark using OpenBLAS.  However, it doesn't appear that OpenBLAS is actually being used.

The script that I'm running is based on the example provided on the Eigen website (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=How_to_run_the_benchmark_suite).

Is there anything else that needs to be done to properly use OpenBLAS?

Here is a copy of the script that I'm running.

````
OPENBLAS_LIBRARIES=$OPENBLASDIR/build/lib/libopenblas.so
OPENBLAS_INCLUDES=$OPENBLASDIR/build/include

export EIGEN3DIR=/root/eigen-3.3.9
export BUILDDIR=/root/eigen-tests

mkdir $BUILDDIR
cd $BUILDDIR

cmake $EIGEN3DIR -DEIGEN_BUILD_BTL=ON -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=$EIGEN3DIR -DCMAKE_B\
UILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENBLAS_LIBRARIES=$OPENBLAS_LIBRARIES -DOPENBLAS_INCLUDES=\
$OPENBLAS_INCLUDES
cd bench/btl
make -j8
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ctest -V```
````